# Querying multiple database tables without using JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to combine three queries into one and failing miserably.   Everything goes well until I add the "order by" clause.

```
SELECT
wti.price, hh.price, mb.price
FROM
spotprices.wti, spotprices.hh, spotprices.mb
ORDER BY
wti.sdate desc limit 1, hh.sdate desc limit 1, mb.sdate desc limit 1;
```

In essence, I am attempting to get the most recent price by sdate by using the "order by sdate desc limit 1" trick.  Individually, the query works well.

```
SELECT price FROM spotprices.wti ORDER BY wti.sdate desc LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: We stopped writing queries this way in 1992. JOIN us.

Comment: LOL!  Fair enough.  I am not a database guru so I am more than happy to be enlightened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subqueries in the `select`:

```
SELECT (SELECT wti.price FROM spotprices.wti ORDER BY wti.sdate DESC LIMIT 1) as wti_price,
       (SELECT hh.price FROM spotprices.hh ORDER BY hh.sdate DESC LIMIT 1) as hh_price,
       (SELECT mb.price FROM spotprices.mb ORDER BY mb.sdate DESC LIMIT 1) as mb_price;
```

Comment: Thank you for a clear and cogent answer!  Marking as answered.

Comment: @gordon-linhoff  How would one return the three values without providing the column aliases?  I'm still working to master this subquery thing...

Comment: @Notamachine . . . I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @gordon-linhoff   If a user wanted to remove the column aliases (e.g. "as wti_price") only return a set of values and not the column aliases how should the subquery be formed? I attempted to remove the "as xx_price" from each stanza and the query fails.  At least on MySQL.

Comment: @Notamachine . . . It should actually work in MySQL without the column aliases.  Table aliases are needed for subqueries in the `FROM` clause but I don't think they are needed in the `SELECT`.